# Are there any ways of adding in between strings without changing the string into a list - or are strings immutable?

Tags: python, string

I am a beginner in Python, and am doing some simple problems. However, I am having trouble with the following question:

> Define a simple "spelling correction" function correct() that takes a
>   string and sees to it that:
>
> 1) two or more occurrences of the space character is compressed into
>   one, and
>
> 2) inserts an extra space after a period if the period is directly
>   followed by a letter. E.g. correct("This (multiple spaces) is (multiple spaces) very funny (multiple spaces) and (multiple spaces) cool.Indeed!") should return "This is very funny and cool. Indeed!"
>
> Tip: Use regular expressions!

This is my code:

```
def correct(x):
    y = x.split()
    y = list(y)
    for i in y:
        if i == " ":
            for o in y:
                if o == " ":
                    y.remove(o)
        y.insert(y.index(i)," ")
        if i == ".":
            y.insert(y.index(i)+1," ")
    y = " ".join(y)
    return y

print(correct("This   is  very funny  and    cool.Indeed!"))
```

When I ran the program, I got no output. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Are there any other ways of adding in between strings without changing the string into a list? Or are strings immutable?

Comment: Generally, modifying a value while you're looping through it as a bad idea, and you're doing that in several places. Instead of calling all variables `y`, use different letters, or perhaps even use meaningful variable names. This should help you find your problem

Comment: The tip of using regular expressions is a good one by the way, it would definitely simplify this

Comment: take a look at the RegExp substitute function: re.sub() - it will help you to simplify your code dramatically

Comment: Thanks. @Jezzamon I didn't take notice of that tip; I see now how it would simplify the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are immutable, but act similarly to lists. You don't necessarily need to "convert" them to a list. You can do something like:

```
myString = "Insert Here -><- Insert There"
myString = myString[:14] + "Inserted" + mystring[14:]
# => myString == "Insert Here ->Inserted<- Insert There"
```

However, yes, strings are immutable and cannot be 'inserted' into like a list can. For that, you must convert them to a list.

In your case, you may find use in the `re` regular expression module. In order to compress multiple occurances together, you can do something like:

```
import re
answer = re.sub(r' +', r' ', myString)
```

Replace, however, does work because it creates a new instance.

```
>>> s = "Test"
>>> id(s)
41325568
>>> s = s.replace("s", "x")
>>> id(s)
41325600
>>> s
'Text'
>>>
```

So you can easily replace "." with ". " and then run the regular expression to compress it. The end result would look something like:

```
def correct(myString):
    myString = myString.replace(".", ". ") # Even if there is already a space, it doesn't matter
    import re
    return re.sub(r' +', r' ', myString)
```

If you don't want, or are not allowed, to use the `re` module, you can use this one-liner

```
>>> def correct(myString):
...     return ' '.join(myString.replace('.', '. ').split())
...
>>> myString = "This   is  very funny  and    cool.Indeed!"
>>> correct(myString)
'This is very funny and cool. Indeed!'
>>>
```

Note that this does not take into account multiple periods or other punctuation types, or if the last character is a period. It will also collapse other forms of whitespace (tabs, etc). So:
`"In a       galaxy         far,far          away..."`
becomes:
`"In a galaxy far,far away. . ."`

We'd recommend using `re` for this. It's also significantly faster.

Comment: I think that `\s` is more appropriate rather than ` `. Also, you should add a space after the period only if the period is followed by a letter

Comment: Good catch. Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Feel more than free to edit my post. I'm awful with regular expressions. It's on my to-do list.

Answer (score 1):

@ John La Rooy , maybe you code more short.....I recognize myself which i without see your answer , i will not be done...., your are the Master ....

```
def correct(s):
    s = raw_input("Please give a sentece: ")
    return " ".join(s.replace(".", ". ").split())
print correct('s')
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of flexibility - what if you would want to extend your correction rules...

Here is an extendable example:

```
import re

correction_rules = [
 {'search_for': r'[\s]{2,}', 'replace_with': ' '},
 {'search_for': r'(\.)([^\s])', 'replace_with': r'\1 \2'},
]

def correct(s, rules=correction_rules):
    new_s = s
    for r in rules:
        new_s = re.sub(r['search_for'], r['replace_with'], new_s)
    return new_s

print(correct("This   is  very funny  and    cool.Indeed!", correction_rules))
```

Comment: Not sure how strictly we're supposed to read the question, but it doesn't say to replace all whitespace (for example tabs) with spaces, it only says to replace multiple space characters with one space character. Also it only says to add a space after a period if the next character is a letter, not all non-whitespace characters (for example digits).

Comment: @SteveJessop, that's why i did it this way! OP might change the correction rules as he wish... ;)

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Anyway I find it amusing that the question itself contains text where adding a space between a period and a letter is wrong so far as English is concerned: `E.g.`!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done quite simply without regex. Notice that you can always add extra space after '.' as you'll strip the spurious ones in the second step.

```
>>> def correct(s):
...     s = s.replace(".", ". ")
...     s = " ".join(s.split())
...     return s
... 
>>> print(correct("This   is  very funny  and    cool.Indeed!"))
This is very funny and cool. Indeed!
```